# Powershell "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar1] Not Working in pipeline

Tags: json, powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml

In a devops pipeline Im using a powershell script in a YAML file to read a json parameter file and push these values into YAML variables.

I can successfully read and extract the parameters

```
ScriptType: InlineScript
Inline: |
$params = Get-Content main.parameters.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json 
$clientname = Out-String -InputObject $params.parameters.clientname
$clientname = $clientname.ToLower()
```

but when i try to set the variables using

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar2]$clientname"
```

it does not set the testvar2 to the $clientname value - however if i explicitly assign a string value to the variable $clientname = 'pickles' - this does update the variable.
The $clientname type returns as a string. Is there something to do with how the json keys are returned?

[full code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhADu.png)

[output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWtGd.png)

**EDIT**:
I can read the json absolutely fine - $clientname is populated with the correct value - the issue is when i try to assign it to a YAML variable using task.setvariable. If you look at the full code the $newclientname works as expected e.g populates the yAML variable - $clientname does not.

Comment: how does your json looks like ?

Comment: Ho it's an ARM parameter file ? are you just trying to get the value of the parameter ? probably `$params.parameters.clientname.value`  ?